# multi email send

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtpclient

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending an email to multiple addresses / recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209129/sending-an-email-to-multiple-addresses-recipients)

I am using the below code, and it only sends one email -  I have to send multiple emails.

For getting more than one email I use:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["email_data"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection con100 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd100 = new OleDbCommand("select top 3 emails  from bulk_tbl", con100);
        OleDbDataAdapter da100 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd100);
        DataSet ds100 = new DataSet();
        da100.Fill(ds100);
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds100.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            //try
            {
                string all_emails = ds100.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                {
                    string allmail = all_emails + ";";
                    Session.Add("ad_emails",allmail);
                    Response.Write(Session["ad_emails"]);
                    send_mail();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and for sending one email I use

```
    string sendto = Session["ad_emails"].ToString();

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage("info@abc.com", sendto, "subject", "body");
    SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("mail.smtp.com");
    System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc", "abc");
    emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    emailClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
    emailClient.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the sending portion of the code in a loop. The following line:

```
emailClient.Send(message);
```

only sends **one** email, for example.