# Unable to send an email to multiple addresses/recipients using C#

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am using the below code, and it only sends one email - I have to send the email to multiple addresses.

For getting more than one email I use:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["email_data"].ConnectionString;
OleDbConnection con100 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
OleDbCommand cmd100 = new OleDbCommand("select top 3 emails  from bulk_tbl", con100);
OleDbDataAdapter da100 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd100);
DataSet ds100 = new DataSet();
da100.Fill(ds100);

    for (int i = 0; i < ds100.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    //try
    {
        string all_emails = ds100.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
        {
            string allmail = all_emails + ";";
            Session.Add("ad_emails",allmail);
            Response.Write(Session["ad_emails"]);
            send_mail();
        }
    }
```

and for sending the email I use:

```
string sendto = Session["ad_emails"].ToString();

MailMessage message = new MailMessage("info@abc.com", sendto, "subject", "body");
SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("mail.smtp.com");
System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc", "abc");
emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
emailClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
emailClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: Please check the code posted here.  When I reformatted it I found an extra set of `{ }`.  I don't think that was intentional so I removed them.  Just click the edit link above if you want to put them back.

Comment: Putting a , for separating different emails and create a MailAddress object won't work! Check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498968/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-address-using-system-net-mail

Answer (score 60):

The problem is that you are supplying a list of addresses separated by semi-colons to the `MailMessage` constructor when it only takes a string representing a single address:

> A String that contains the address of the recipient of the e-mail message.

or possibly a list separated by commas (see below).

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k0ddab0.aspx)

To specify multiple addresses you need to use the [`To`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to.aspx) property which is a [`MailAddressCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection.aspx), though the examples on these pages don't show it very clearly:

```
message.To.Add("one@example.com, two@example.com"));
```

> The e-mail addresses to add to the MailAddressCollection. Multiple e-mail addresses must be separated with a comma character (",").

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695.aspx)

so creating the `MailMessage` with a *comma* separated list should work.

Comment: Do you have a full example from this functionality?

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me.
(recipients is an Array of Strings)

```
//Fuse all Receivers
var allRecipients = String.Join(",", recipients);

//Create new mail
var mail = new MailMessage(sender, allRecipients, subject, body);

//Create new SmtpClient
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(hostname, port);

//Try Sending The mail
try
{
    smtpClient.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(String.Format("MailAppointment: Could Not Send Mail. Error = {0}",ex), this);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This function validates a comma- or semicolon-separated list of email addresses:

```
public static bool IsValidEmailString(string emailAddresses)
{
    try
    {
        var addresses = emailAddresses.Split(',', ';')
            .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a))
            .ToArray();

        var reformattedAddresses = string.Join(",", addresses);

        var dummyMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        dummyMessage.To.Add(reformattedAddresses);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would need to be .Where(a=> !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a)).ToArray(); instead

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  I've updated the code, though I use the .NET 4.0 function `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Answer (score 4):

To send to multiple recipients I set up my recipient string with a comma as my separator.

```
string recipient = "foo@bar.com,foo2@bar.com,foo3@bar.com";
```

Then to add the recipients to the `MailMessage` object:

```
string[] emailTo = recipient.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < emailTo.GetLength(0); i++)
    mailMessageObject.To.Add(emailTo[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code I  use for send multiple mail for to, bcc and cc

```
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
Attachment a = new Attachment(attach);
email.From = new MailAddress(from);//De
string[] Direcciones;
char[] deliminadores = { ';' };

//Seleccion de direcciones para el parametro to
Direcciones = to.Split(deliminadores);
foreach (string d in Direcciones)
email.To.Add(new MailAddress(d));//Para

//Seleccion de direcciones para el parametro CC
Direcciones = CC.Split(deliminadores);
foreach (string d in Direcciones)
email.CC.Add(new MailAddress(d));

//Seleccion de direcciones para el parametro Bcc
Direcciones = Bcc.Split(deliminadores);
foreach (string d in Direcciones)
enter code here`email.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are also allowed to pass `MailMessage.To.Add()`a [comma separated list of valid RFC 822 e-mail addresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765823(v=office.15).aspx):

```
Nathaniel Borenstein <nsb@bellcore.com>, Ned Freed <ned@innosoft.com>
```

So the code would be:

```
message.To.Add("Nathaniel Borenstein <nsb@bellcore.com>, Ned Freed <ned@innosoft.com>");
```

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.