# An invalid character was found in the mail header ;

Tags: asp.net

An invalid character was found in the mail header: ';'.

```
String s="arun@gamil.com,mohan@gmail.com";

MailMessage oMailMessage = new MailMessage();
oMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(s));
oMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(oSmtpSection.From);
```

I am getting error in `oMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(s));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498968/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-address-using-system-net-mail

Comment: thanks!  I have done and replace oMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(s)); to oMailMessage.To.Add(s);

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
MailMessage oMailMessage = new MailMessage();
oMailMessage.Body = ....;
oMailMessage.To.Add("arun@gamil.com");
oMailMessage.To.Add("mohan@gmail.com");

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Send(oMailMessage);
```