# MailMessage.To.Add() throwing exception : "An invalid character was found in the mail header: ','."

Tags: c#, smtp

**I am getting this error when I am using it in sharepoint project, while in console app its working fine**

I am using `MailMessage` class to send email using SMTP .
But when I trying to add user to 'To' property I am getting {"An invalid character was found in the mail header: ','."} exception, which I think something fishy is happening here as ',' is allowed to separate multiple users . [Adding multiple user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695.aspx)

** Multiple e-mail addresses must be separated with a comma character (",").**

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

 mailMessage.To.Add("amir_khan@enter.com,walter_white@yahoo.com,");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? [How to send email to multiple address using System.Net.Mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498968/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-address-using-system-net-mail)

Comment: @Izzy Sorry but I tried to search in stackoverflow but can't find any resolution for this particular scenario i.e MailMessage doesn't accepting ',' character while it's written in MSDN. Its regarding the exception

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Got the culprit: **It's the extra comma(**,**) at the end of last email address**

```
mailMessage.To.Add("amir_khan@enter.com,walter_white@yahoo.com,");
```

Remove the trailing comma and it will work:

```
mailMessage.To.Add("amir_khan@enter.com,walter_white@yahoo.com");
```

If this does not work in SharePoint then please add each address separately onto MailMessage object like below;

```
foreach (var address in StringofEmails.Split(",")) {
    MailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(address.Trim(), ""));
}
```

Comment: If you recipients is in a collection you could use `string recipients = String.Join(",", _config.NotificationSettings.MailSettings.Recipients);`

Answer (score 14):

I got the error even though I don't have a comma at the end. It turns out that I need to leave a space after the comma

I have to change my code from a string.Join(",", emailList) to string.Join(", ", emailList)

Following didn't work for me.

```
mailMessage.To.Add("amir_khan@enter.com,walter_white@yahoo.com");
```

Following worked for me(Observe that there is space after the comma).

```
mailMessage.To.Add("amir_khan@enter.com, walter_white@yahoo.com");
```

Comment: This was my issue after I upgraded from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.7.2. They must have introduced stricter parsing rules.

Comment: Placing the space would mean the first is the email (amir_khan@enter.com,) and the second is the name(walter_white@yahoo.com).  I dont think it would send it to the second person(walter_white@yahoo.com). Did you confirm it sent to both emails?

Comment: Hey @RobertSmith, Yes it worked when I tried back then using .net framework 4.6+. I didn’t tried it recently.

Answer (score 2):

I can't replicate this. The above code works for me. Maybe try to add them using a seperate 'To' each time.

```
mailMessage.To.Add(x);
mailMessage.To.Add(y);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but is there any issue in using specified in question ?

Comment: @Nee I couldn't find one sorry, I copied your code directly into my VS and had no problems with it :? Maybe a VS restart might help, or try adding a space after the comma?

Comment: I am getting this error only when I am using it in sharepoint project but not in console application or other

Comment: There are classes for Smtp in both System.Web and System.Net. In one you must use comma, in the other you must use semi colon. Don't remember which was which. The one in System.Net is the one that is recommended if I remember correctly...

Comment: Semi colon doesn't work with System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Answer (score -1):

I had to update a project with nicer looking emails and I published the web project and got this error.

Mine was from some debug code in which

```
currentUser = myname@mycompany.com
```

got added

```
MailAddress mailAddressUser = new MailAddress(currentUser + "@mycompany.com");
```

Essentially:

```
myname@mycompany.com@mycompany.com
```

So instead of an issue with a trailing comma,  literally another @

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this as well.
This approach also validates the email address before adding it to the dl list.
So you will only valid dl list.

```
var emails = ("amir_khan@enter.com,walter_white@yahoo.com,").Split(',');
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
foreach (var email from emails)
{
     var emailAddressAttribute = new EmailAddressAttribute();
     if(emailAddressAttribute.IsValid(email))
     {
          MailMessage.To.Add(email);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?