# Send a mail in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, email

A question regarding send mail in mvc 3.

When I click on `btnApply` it should send 2 emails to `abcd@gmail.com` and also send an acknowledgement to (who filled email id in apply form like be `123@gmail.com`)

For example:

- **Email1** : `xyz@gamail.com`
- **Email2** : `abcd@gmail.com`
- **Email3** : email entered in apply form, e.g `123@gmail.com`

when a **Email3** click apply send mail from **Email1(Sender)** to **Email2(receiver)** & **Email3(receiver)**

**or**

when a **Email3** click apply send mail from **Email2(Sender)** to **Email2(receiver)** & **Email3(receiver)**

1. I have form in popup:

   ```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()){
    Your Full Name
       <input type="text" value="" id="txtname" name="txtname" required />
       Your Email          
       <input type="email" value="" id="txtemail" name="txtemail"  required />    
       Upload Your Resume
       <input name="Upload Saved Replay" id="btnFile" type="file" />
       <input type="button" id="btnApply" name="btnApply" value="Apply" />
   }
   ```
2. I have a email manager, it only send 1 mail that from  xyz@gmail.com to email id that specified in apply form (123@gmail.com )

   ```
   public class EmailManager
   {
       private const string EmailFrom = "xyz@gmail.com";
       public static void Enquiry( int JobId, string UserName, string Email, string Massage)
       {
           using (var client = new SmtpClient()) {
               using (var message = new MailMessage(EmailFrom, Email)) {
                   message.Subject = "Successful";
                   message.Body = "<html><head><meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /></head><body><p>Dear " + UserName +
                       ", </p> <p>Thankyou for Registering</p>"
                       + "</a></p><div>Best regards,</div><div>Nisha</div></body></html>";
                   message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                   client.EnableSsl = true;
                   client.Send(message);
               };
           };
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: in your code `EmailFrom` is `xyz@gmail.com` so why do you want to send it to the same `xyz@gmail.com`

Comment: I think you should be clear as to what you want to do. Which ones are `EmailFrom` and which ones you sending to `Email`. If you clarify that it is easier to know how to send your email. Also if you want other `Email`s copied into the **email** you are sending indicate it clearly

Comment: Rename your variable `EmailFrom` to `EmailTo` for easier understanding and for best practice i suggest you comment your code to make it easier to read

Comment: does your code even run? if it does what happens when it runs?

Comment: for the meantime look at this it should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498968/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-address-using-system-net-mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a for loop between two usings.

```
string[] Emails = { Email,"abcd@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.com" }

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
    using (var message = new MailMessage(EmailFrom, Emails[i]))
    {   
        message.Subject = "Successful";
        message.Body = "<html><head><meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /></head><body><p>Dear " + UserName +
        ", </p> <p>Thankyou for Registering</p>"
        + "</a></p><div>Best regards,</div><div>Nisha</div></body></html>";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(message);
    };
}
```

Variable Email comes from void Enquiry, others are hard coded

Comment: thanks but is this possible to hard code Email2 : abcd@gmail.com ??

Comment: this will send same email to the same person 3 times