# System.Net.Mail.MailAddress send to multiple emails with one parameter

Tags: c#, .net, system.net.mail

I've just switched from the deprecated `System.Web.Mail.MailAddress` to `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress`, but it doesn't seem to be particularly flexible when passing in a parameter holding multiple addresses when using the new `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.To.Add`.

```
string emailAdd= "email1@emailus.com; email2@emailus.com";

System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.To.Add(emailAdd);
```

In the above example, `email2@emailus.com` is emailed successfully, but `email1@emailus.com` is not.  I really need a way to do this since my addresses are defined in another class and passed to an `email()` method via a parameter.  I'm simply not passing five parameters for 5 separate emails.  Or indeed one and splicing on my end, `.Web` version is proving to be way more versatile.

This question is **not** a duplicate of the suggested one.  The answer to the "duplicate" is add them individually, I want to add multiple addresses simultaneously.  Since there is a way to do this, this question is more relevant than the one I'm accused of duplicating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email to multiple address using System.Net.Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498968/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-address-using-system-net-mail)

Comment: It isn't.  He asks how to send to multiple emails, I'm asking how to send to multiple emails with one parameter.

Comment: System.Net.Mail.MailAddress 
To is not a member of mail address. 
Downvote

Comment: @pianocomposer, good spot and good downvote.  I'm not sure where I got that from...  has the API changed?  Maybe this is outdated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695(v=vs.110).aspx), the `.Add()` method accepts a string of **comma-delimited** addresses, rather than semicolon-delimited.

Therefore either changing the parameter that you are passing in to a comma-delimited string, if possible, or adding functionality to your email method to replace the semicolons with commas should resolve the issue.

Comment: Omg, I skimmed that line and thought the comma was a semi colon, thanks worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

In this purpose you can follow the function Parameter that it denotes actually which is show that you can use comma delimiter and function parameter is denoted as addresses which identify that you can send multiple email together using it

```
mail.To.Add("to1mailaddress@domain,to2mailaddress@domain");
```