# Mail doesn't work with multiple to addresses

Tags: c#, sendmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to send an email to multiple addresses/recipients using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209129/sending-an-email-to-multiple-addresses-recipients)

I have used below code to send mail in script task

```
 string MailFromName = "Admin";
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailobj = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            System.Net.Mail.MailAddress MailFrom = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(MailFromEmail, MailFromName);
            System.Net.Mail.MailAddress MailTo = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(MailToEmail, MailToEmail);
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailmsg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(MailFrom, MailTo);
            mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailmsg.Subject = strMessageSubject;
            mailmsg.Body = strMessageBody;
            mailobj.Host = strSMTPServerName;
            mailobj.Send(mailmsg);
```

It is working fine when I am using MailToEmail as "myaddress@myMail.com" i.e. for one email address

but this doesn't send any mail(also it dosen't fail) when I have multiple adress in to list

ex: "MyAdress@MyMail.com; MySecondAddress@MyMail.com"

How to resolve this?

**EDIT** New Code

```
 string MailFromName = "Admin";
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailobj = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            System.Net.Mail.MailAddress MailFrom = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(MailFromEmail, MailFromName);
            System.Net.Mail.MailAddress MailTo = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(MailToEmail, MailToEmail);
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailmsg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(MailFrom, MailTo);
            mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailmsg.Subject = strMessageSubject;
            mailmsg.Body = strMessageBody;
            foreach (string str in multipleToMsg)
            {
                mailmsg.To.Add(str);
            }


            mailobj.Host = strSMTPServerName;
            mailobj.Send(mailmsg);
```

Comment: _How_ do you add multiple addresses? That seems to be the key code and it's missing.

Comment: Is your mail MailToEmail variable a comma separated string?

Comment: MailToEmail is a string variable which has multiple address seperated with **;**

Comment: `using System.Net.Mail` would have spared you a lot of clutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've not shown how exactly you are adding the recipients. However to add multiple recipients you add to the "To" collection:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add("sillyjoe@stackoverflow.com");
```

"To" is a collection of MailAddresses. Make sure you are adding it to that collection and not attempting to concatenate email addresses all into one MailAddress object.

Comment: I believe I am doing same here System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailmsg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(MailFrom, MailTo);

Comment: Not quite, the constructor allows you to only pass in one recipient. If you want to give it multiple recipients you cannot use the constructor, you must add to the collection afterwards.

Comment: Then How can I modify my Current code :-( I am failing to do that. When I am creating message object I am not able to add from address

Comment: Please check my edit part, I am still not able to get the mail

Comment: From can be specified by doing mailmsg.From. Show us the string of emails.

Comment: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress'**

Comment: mail1@company.com; mail2.company.com;

Comment: Oops ! my mistake ! now it is fine thanks :-) +1

Answer (score 2):

Accoring to [MSDN: MailMessage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to.aspx) the "To" property is a collection of MailAddresses

so you just need to do something like

```
mailmsg.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(MailToEmail, MailToEmail)); 
mailmsg.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(MailToEmail2, MailToEmail2))
```

or in a foreach loop

```
//get email addresses into a collection called emailAdds
foreach (var emailAdd in emailAdds)
{
    mailmsg.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(emailAdd, emailAdd )); 
}
```

Comment: As my Mail adress are coming from the database I may not know how many to address are there. :-(

Comment: yeah you can use a for/foreach loop there.  I just used it to show you how to add multiple items

Answer (score 0):

To specify multiple addresses you need to use the To property which is a [MailAddressCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection.aspx)

```
message.To.Add("one@example.com, one@example.com"));
message.To.Add("two@example.com, two@example.com"));
```