# How do I add another email address in my C#?

Tags: c#, .net, email, email-validation, system.net.mail

I would like to add an extra email address for messages to be sent/forwarded to when the email form submit button is clicked, whats the easiest way to do this?

```
public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = txtName.Text;
    string emailaddress = txtEmail.Text;
    string body = txtComment.Text;


    MailAddress From = new MailAddress(emailaddress);
    MailAddress To = new MailAddress("111@1111.com");
    MailMessage email = new MailMessage(From, To);
    email.Subject = "Comment from Website from " + name;
    email.Body = body;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.1111.com");
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("111@1111.com", "1111111111");
    smtp.Send(email);
    email.Dispose();

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Email Confirm", "alert('Email Sent!');", true);

    txtComment.Text = "";
    txtEmail.Text = "";
    txtName.Text = "";


}
protected void txtEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
}
```

We'll say that my extra email address is smtp.2222.com   222@2222.com with an authentication of 22222.  Thanks for looking folks.

Comment: A new email address or a new SMTP client?  If it's a new email address, there should be a `CC` property in your MailMessage object.  If it's an SMTP client, you have to execute this twice, once for each SMTP client.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm still new to C#. The new email address would be a facebook email address, where as the original is not.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why a new question needed to be opened for this. For example, a post here asks the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209129/sending-an-email-to-multiple-addresses-recipients.  A quick google search of "send email c# multiple recipients" brings you back hundreds of relevant results.  It's OK to ask questions, just please do research on your own first.

Comment: And theres that one guy.

Comment: I apologize if I seemed gruff, but I'm also an engineering instructor, and sometimes I feel that being blunt is the best way to get a point across. If a student asks me a question that I know he can answer on his own, I tell him to do so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using the `To.Add` method, you can pass a comma separated list of email address to `MailMessage` constructor which is a much better solution especially if you have more than a few email addresses to send the email to...

```
var from = "me@me.com";
var to = "mail1@domain.com,mail2@domain.com,mail3@domain.com";
var subject = "My Subject";
var body = "Message Body";
var message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
```

will work just as well...

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your input!  c#, and web development in general, has really been testing my learning curve. I'd one up you both, but it seems my rep keeps getting negative hits.

Comment: Np, I'd love to hear from the person who downvoted this because it most certainly works and it saves lines of code...

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
…
MailAddress From = new MailAddress(emailaddress);
MailMessage email = new MailMessage(from, to);
email.To.Add(new MailAddress("111@1111.com"));
email.To.Add(new MailAddress("222@2222.com"));
email.Subject = "Comment from Website from " + name;
email.Body = body;
…
```