# How to send mails to multiple reciepients from web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have developed a asp.net Mvc 4 project and now i am planing to integrate a Mail system in my application.Initially i taught like integrating mail System in my existing web application but later i moved it to a console application using Scheduler to send mail at some time interval.

My scenario is like i have a list of mail ids and i need to send mail to all these mail ids . I have checked System.Web.Mail and i found i can only give one email address at a time. Is it possible in System.Web.Mail or is there any other library available to achieve my scenario.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to send an email to multiple addresses/recipients using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209129/unable-to-send-an-email-to-multiple-addresses-recipients-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`To` in `System.Net.Mail` is a `MailAddressCollection`,so you can add how many addresses you need.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(...);
msg.To.Add(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Chris's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22060011/7793) answer is correct but you may want to also consider using a mail service. Here are some you could try - they all have a free tier to get started on.

- http://sendgrid.com/
- http://www.mailgun.com/
- https://mandrill.com/
- http://aws.amazon.com/ses/

Comment: I second this suggestion. In the first mail system I ever incorporated into an application, I used a local SMTP server. This resulted in some deliverability issues, mostly false-positive spam flagging. Let some other service do the job, you just send them the email addresses and the content. Amazon SES is a dirt cheap option that more or less functions like a 3rd party SMTP server, so there is almost no integration work to be done... quick and easy.

Comment: @Gadget27 - Thanks, I've added a link to Amazon SES

Answer (score 0):

You can easily sent emails to more than one recipient. Here is a sample that uses a SMTP server to send an email to multiple addreses:

```
//using System.Net.Mail;

public void SendEmail(){

    MailMessage email = new MailMessage();

    email.To.Add("first@email.com");
    email.To.Add("second@email.com");
    email.To.Add("third@email.com");

    email.From = new MailAddress("me@email.com");

    string smtpHost = "your.SMTP.host";
    int smtpPort = 25;

    using(SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, smtpPort)){
        mailClient.Send(email);
    }
}
```

Just a note: if you go with SMTP, you should probably have a look also on MSDN for the [SmtpClient.Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, just to be sure you are catching any related exceptions.